# Get data from JSONObject

Tags: java, json

I have a `JSONObject` and want to get a `String` out of it and save it.

```
SelVehicleJSON (JSONObject):
{
  "selVehicle":
  {
     "_id":"5b38be73257303206ce9b8f9",
     "userId":"5b34c591cb6084255857e338"
  }
}
```

I tried

```
String vehicleId = selVehicleJSON.getString("_id");
```

but I get the error

> W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for _id`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What about using `userId` instead?

Comment: same problem still

Comment: You have another object inside SelVehicleJSON -> selVehicle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hierarchy seems to be

> selVehicle._id

Or set the root before doing

> selVehicleJSON.getString("_id");

**Edit 1**

Try using [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath). It makes the life easier and keeps the code clean. 
In your case, the code will look like:

```
public String getValue(JSONObject json, String path) {
    return JsonPath.read(json.toString(), path);
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah, you are right about the hierarchy. I still can't fetch the data with                      vehicleId = selVehicleJSON.getString("selVehicle._id"); Or how does the code have to be? Can you explain what you mean with setting the route? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this :

```
JSONObject selVehicle =  selVehicleJSON.get("selVehicle");

String id = selVehicle.get("_id");
```

Comment: Please explain your answer rather than post a code dump answer. This way it will be helpful to all and not just the original poster.

Answer (score 0):

You have two json objects. The outer one is selVehicle and there is a inner json object. So first get the outer json object and use getString on the returned json object.

Try to use this:

```
import java.io.File;
import static org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToString;
import org.json.JSONObject;

File file = new File("Input your json filePath here");
String text = readFileToString(file);
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(text);
jsonObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("selVehicle");
System.out.println(jsonObject.getString("_id"));
```